# Show by simple examples that in Null space Theorem the conditions that T be compact and lambda different of zero cannot be omitted.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Null space Theorem: Let $T: X \rightarrow X\ $ be a compact linear
operator on a normed space $X$. Then for every $\lambda \neq 0$ the null space $N(T_\lambda)$, with $T_\lambda = T -\lambda I \ $ is finite dimensional.

Show by simple examples that in Null space Theorem the conditions that $T$ be compact and  $\lambda \neq 0 \ $  cannot be omitted.

I tried to use the fact that if $X$ is infinite in dimension then the identity operator cannot be compact, however, I couldn't guarantee the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity $I:X\to X$ is compact if, and only if, the unit closed ball $\bar B_X$ is compact if, and only if, $X$ is finite dimensional.

- omitting the compacity hypothesis : $T = \lambda I$ has $\ker(T-\lambda I) = X$, which can be infinite dimensional.
- omitting $\lambda = 0$ : the zero operator is always compact, and its kernel is $X$, which can be infinite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is it possible to get an example that doesn't depend directly on X space?

Comment: No : the counterexample I gave just use that $X$ is infinite dimensional, and you need $X$ to be infinite dimensional for the result of the theorem to fail to be true.